# Retrieve all the deleted files

Tags: macos, terminal, recycle-bin

I deleted all the `PDF` files from the desktop with the command

```
  find . -name '*.pdf' -delete
```

Is there an option to get them back? I look into the recycle bin and seems 
they are not there. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: No, how to do that?

Comment: Can you use some recovery software?

Comment: Vast majority of command line tools has no concept of recycle bin. What filesystem? The easy method is to copy the files from backup (if you have one).

Comment: Yes, which one?

Comment: No backup sorry

Comment: Note: using the filesystem (unless read-only) decreases your chances of recovery. Again: what filesystem? HFS+?

Comment: Time Machine... That's what backups are for.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. The recycle bin functionality is part of the `Finder.app`, and will be used only if you choose to remove files via Finder. Console commands (such as `rm`) will bypass the recycle bin.

There *might* be some file system level utilities to get files back, if (and only if) the space hasn't been overwritten yet... but there are no builtin tools I know of.

I'd recommend to use your last backup.